# Swift int constructor to convert hex string

Tags: swift

All these calls return `nil` for me:

```
Int("ff000000", radix: 16)
Int("#ff000000", radix: 16)
Int("0xff000000", radix: 16)
```

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: The first one works... The second one is invalid, there's no Int initializer that accepts this "CSS" notation. The third one could just be `Int(0xff000000)`.

Comment: Before I posted, i stepped over the 3 lines and checked the result which was nil all way through. However, worst comes to worst, I will wrie my own routine. But before i do that, I will double-check today if my eyes were somehow lying o me yesterday :)

Comment: Accodringly to playground the first line works, the other two do not. But in my project exact same code (in a separate function) shows result as nil. Maybe the debugger is lying to me - I will report back

Comment: I am giving up - making my own routine :)

Comment: I found somehow it worked when only having "ffffff". I am not sure whatt the problem was, but I have no made my own function hat splits off alpha/opacity and then "or" the two values together again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this code, this is working properly.**

```
let value1 = Int64("aabb00ddff",radix: 16)
```

[image]

**The instead of using `Int` you should use `Int64`, because when you convert Hex to Int resulted value will be bigger than expected.**

Int will also work.

Comment: @EricD. Here I am talking about range of Value, you can use Int64 on 32bit devices also.  http://totallyswift.com/number-types-swift/ check this link from more.

Comment: I will accept his answer although it was what I already did. maybe my system is odd somehow since I had to resort to a convoluted soluion.